# Site work correctly on localhost but does not work on server correctly

Tags: php, database, image, server, localhost

I write a website with PHP and my website work correctly on localhost but don't work correctly on server.for example it connect to database but can not read information from database and images does not load correctly in slide show.
And does not show table correctly.many page load in the one page.
You can see the site "qashqai-clinic.ir"

- On localhost

[image]

- On server

  [image]

Comment: Check your error log, general issue is the PHP version that differs.

Comment: Looks like the DB query failed, perhaps using `mysql_*` and webserver is running PHP 7? Check logs.

Comment: Please include the code that generates the page AND the relevant logs. :)

Comment: Mostly the issue occurs because of no database configurations and PHP version issues. also as they said above depricated SQL queries could also be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stab in the dark, but I think your serverside website has errors, but are not displayed because of the production settings.

Try adding the below code on top of your php script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
```

If there is any error, you might be able to see it.